# What Features of Quickbooks for Windows are Missing from the OS X version

Tags: windows, macos, mac, quickbooks

I'd like to use my computer to keep better track of my financials, and I'd like to use quick books to do this.

I own a Mac, and would rather not run a virtual machine just for my accounting program.  However, I've heard that the Mac version of Quickbooks is not a feature for feature port of the PC version, but people rarely go into specifics.

1. What features of Quickbooks on OS X are missing, when compared to the PC version?
2. Does Quickbooks for OS X have features that the PC version doesn't have?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to their website.  I googled your first question and it was the second link, an entire list of the feature differences between Windows and Mac.

Google is your friend.

http://quickbooks.intuit.com/product/accounting-software/pro-mac-business-accounting-software.jsp

Comment: To be fair to the questioner, there are a multitude of minor gotchas (that the linked list doesn't address) between the various versions of Quickbooks (Win vs Mac included). I'm no longer familiar with the current Windows versions so I can't answer more precisely.

Comment: Daisetsu, is there a reason to believe that Intuit's website has good quality information?  I do not see any place on Intuit's website where misleading or incomplete answers can be corrected by users or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The Intuit website lists some differences , but there is strong evidence that the Intuit website is rubbish.

For example:

- Intuit puts BootCamp, Parallels, Fusion, and Virtual PC together in one question and says "Intuit has not tested, nor do we support, the use of a QuickBooks for Windows product on the above mentioned PC emulators."  BootCamp is not an emulator, it is a collection of Windows device drivers for Apple's hardware.  The user launches un-altered Windows on real, not simulated hardware.  The suggestion that this is like running an emulator is depressingly stupid.
- Intuit says that one of the features that is not available in QuickBooks for Mac is making an accountant's copy, and also says that one of the features for QuickBooks for Mac is the ability to make an accountant's copy.
- Intuit says that QuickBooks for Mac cannot make online payments, and also provides a list of all the institutions which Quickbooks for Mac can access in order to download transactions and make payments.

This is not an exhaustive list of the contradictions on the website.